# Preciso levar o id do paciente da table para a próxima pagina, junto com o usuário, ao clicar no botão

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

```
<?php
$conexao = new mysqli("localhost","root","","hospital");

if($conexao->connect_errno){
    echo"Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conexao->connect_errno   .") " . $conexao->connect_error;
}

$res = $conexao->query("SELECT nome, idade, cpf from paciente, ficha_atendimento, questionario WHERE paciente.id = ficha_atendimento.id_paciente AND paciente.id = questionario.id_paciente");


echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
echo "<tr>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>Idade</td>
        <td>CPF</td>
        </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    echo "<tr class='info'>
    <td>". $row['nome']."</td>
    <td>". $row['idade']."</td>
    <td>". $row['cpf']."</td>
    <td><a href='sala_questionario.php'><button class='btn btn-info'>Redirecionar</button></a></td>
    </tr>";
}

echo "</table>";


?>
```

A tabela 'paciente' tem os campos nome idade e cpf, e todos estes estão sendo printados na table, junto à um botão (no código acima) que redireciona o paciente para uma pagina que ele responderá um questionário. Porém, estou precisando levar o id deste paciente para esta próxima página quando ele for redirecionado, para que quando ele responder o questionário o programa envie os dados para a tabela 'questionário' que tem uma chave estrangeira chamada id_paciente que corresponde ao id do paciente da tabela 'paciente'.(ou seja, o problema é que todos estão sendo redirecionados para a mesma página, sem a diferenciação de quem está respondendo o questionário).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando o método `?_GET`, ficaria desta forma:

```
<td><a href='sala_questionario.php?id=$row['id']'><button class='btn btn-info'>Redirecionar</button></a></td>
```

E na página `sala_questionario`, para você pegar o valor, ficaria assim:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC\mostrar_questionario.php on line 24 - aparece esse erro

Comment: E qual seria a line 24?

Comment: <td><a href='sala_questionario.php?id=$row['id']'><button class='btn btn-info'>Redirecionar</button></a></td>

Comment: Tente definir a variavel id antes de passa-la pelo get. `$id = $row ['id'];` e `<td><a href='sala_questionario.php?id=$id'><button class='btn btn-info'>Redirecionar</button></a></td> `

Comment: Então mano, eu tentei de diversas formas e funcionou essa ultima que vc mandou quando eu troco o 'id' pelo cpf, que também serve pois eu posso pegar o id depois através do cpf, já que ninguém vai tem o mesmo cpf. Porém, ele ta printando a página sala_questionário na página que está o botão e não trocando de página. Se não der para resolver isso a gente da um hide() na tabela com os botões e já era. O problema que restou mesmo é que o get que você me pasosu não está funcionando. Aparece isso: Notice: Undefined index: cpf in C:\xampp\htdocs\TCC\sala_questionario.php on line 10. Linha 10 ta o get

Comment: Atualize a sua pergunta com o novo php, para que eu possa te ajudar.

Comment: Opa mano, eu não tinha visto que tava trocando a página. Ta funcionando direitinho mano, agora é só dar hide na tabela q por algum motivo ela vai junto pra outra página hahah. Mas isso ai eu faço de boa, Brigadão cara, ajudou muito !! Desculpa qualquer coisa <3

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta.